# Como "achatar" uma lista de listas de inteiros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma lista de listas

```
d = [[1],[2],[3],[3]]
```

E gostaria de transformá-la em uma lista

```
s = [1,2,3,3]
```

Não entendo bem a diferença entre `d` e `s`, porém preciso fazer a transformação porque eu consigo usar o comando `set(s)` em `s`, mas não consigo usar em `d`. Quero usar `set(d)` porque preciso de uma coleção sem repetições.

Como transformo `d` em `s`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para obter a saída concatenada de um iterável use o método [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) disponibilizado no módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html).

```
from itertools import chain

d = [[1],[2],[3],[3]]

print(set(chain.from_iterable(d)))  #{1, 2, 3}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/KA63iA)</sup>

Ou então utilize [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) desempacotando a lista com o [operador *](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
from itertools import chain

d = [[1],[2],[3],[3]]

print(set(chain(*d)))               #{1, 2, 3}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/U62NeL)</sup>

Quanto a diferença entre:

- `s = [1,2,3,3]`
- `d = [[1],[2],[3],[3]]`

A lista em `s` é uma lista composta por inteiros enquanto a lista em `d` é uma lista composta por listas compostas por inteiros.

Comment: Boa resposta, Augusto! Só fiquei na dúvida porque não sou - digamos - proficiente em Python. Mas deduzindo a partir do comportamento do JS (que é a linguagem que eu mais conheço), o `set` não remove o `[3]` _duplicado_ porque cada _sub lista_ criada literalmente ali tem um endereço (i.e. referência) diferente, certo? :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe: Em python uma das [finalidades de `set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) é remover membros duplicados de iteráveis. Já o `chain()` ele se comporta analogamente ao javascript [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Answer (score 7):

Para complementar as respostas, seguem duas alternativas que encontrei no Stack Overflow em Inglês: [*How to make a flat list out of list of lists?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/664577)

### 1. Usando sum

```
d = [[1],[2],[3],[3]]
flattened_list = sum(d, [])
```

Essa implementação utiliza diretamente propriedades de monóides, mas pode não ser muito eficiente para listas grandes.

### 2. Usando reduce

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

d = [[1],[2],[3],[3]]
flattened_list = reduce(operator.concat, d)
```

Essa versão também usa um dialeto funcional (redução), e é uma alternativa a implementação com `chain` da [resposta do Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495261/100).

#### [Veja as soluções funcionando no ideone.com](https://ideone.com/bum4bB)

Answer (score 5):

Para transformar **d** em **s** você pode implementar dois laços de repetições aninhados. Neste caso o código ficaria:

```
d = [[1], [2], [3], [3]]
s = list()
for i in d:
    for j in i:
        s.append(j)

print(s)
```

Neste código o primeiro `for` percorre a lista **d** e, em seguida, o segundo `for` percorre cada uma das listas que estão dentro da lista **d**. Posteriormente será exibido a lista contendo os valores.

Agora se preferir utilizar um código mais compacto e conciso, pode utilizar **[List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** e montar o seguinte código:

Ou...

```
d = [[1], [2], [3], [3]]
s = [j for i in d for j in i]
print(s)
```

Agora, se você pretende gerar uma **lista de únicos**, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
d = [[1], [2], [3], [3]]
s = list({j for i in d for j in i})
print(s)
```

Veja maiores explicações na documentação do **[set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)**.

Executando este último código obtemos como resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Outra coisa, como o `set` não garante uma ordenação dos elementos, podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
d = [[1], [2], [3], [3]]
s = sorted({j for i in d for j in i})
print(s)
```

Neste último código não preciso invocar a função `list()`, pois, a função `sorted()` já min retorna uma **lista** com todos os elementos em ordem crescente.